# Reduce Python static library size

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to build a minimal Python static library for distribution in an app. This is the C API I need to link to, I believe it may be called CPython as well. I don't need to package actual Python scripts, just link to the library itself.

I've built 3.7.4 by doing:

```
./configure --disable-shared
make
```

This does build a library *libpython3.7m.a* which is 12.4MB. Is it possible to reduce this size at all? I need an absolute barebones distribution without any of the normal packages. Literally this is just for a scripting bridge and doesn't need any of the usual Python functionality.

Comment: Isn't that the sort of thing that [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/FrontPage) is designed to do? Perhaps you could also look into [micropython](https://micropython.org/)

Comment: Looked it up and says it's for Windows executables? I don't need to package a script, I need a Python library which I link to another program for use a scripting bridge. Sorry if my terms are not right, but I think I've seen this called "CPython" before because the API is C.

Comment: There is [cxFreeze](https://anthony-tuininga.github.io/cx_Freeze/). A Python interpreter is a large piece of software which isn't easy to trim down. It is a difficult wheel to reinvent.

Comment: I'm not trying to freeze scripts. I'm trying to build a static library so I can link to the C API.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to link to [Python's Extension API](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html#stable), you won't find much luck in shaving off size from the libpython shared object. This is because the Extension API uses the same types and headers as the core interpreter (which is why it's called *extensions* instead of something else like plugins), granting the extensions runtime access to the inner mechanics of the interpreter that normal python scripts wouldn't allow. Basically, the libpython object is just the interpreter compiled without an entry point and an additional frontend so that the expression of simple python operations (e.g. parsing function arguments) stays a clean development experience.

If you're using Python 3.2+, there is offered a "Limited API" for the version of python you are trying to target, but the point of this is to guarantee a stable ABI as the extensions API evolves, **not** to reduce the size of the compilation unit.

I would also like to mention that the term CPython is just a way to disambiguate the vanilla Python distribution from similar but incompatible interpreters like Pypy.

Comment: Not sure what the  Python's Extension API is I'm just talking about the C API that has things like https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html. Is that what you mean? 12M seems too large and I suspected that lots of additional libraries like gtk where compiled in.

Comment: @GenericPtr What you just linked is just one page of the Extension API, so we are talking about the same thing. Specifically, what you linked details the types of function pointers that can be assigned to an extension type. This portion (for example) of what you call the C API will require everything related to Python's definition of the PyObject structure (which is the core object). This would be very difficult to separate from the rest of the C API, but there isn't anything in the extensions that defines support for GTK or anything like you said. It is all just python's core.

Comment: maybe that's as small as it gets to embed python in a program. I thought python could be run on embedded hardware without even 12MB of space but maybe I was wrong.

Comment: You may be thinking of micropython which is a separate implementation. https://micropython.org/

Comment: I'm looking in my existing python 3.7 distro (/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib) and I see that libpython3.7.dylib is a symbolic link to the interpreter that is only ~3MB. How did it get so small there? There are lots of libraries which are dynamically linked in (I assume) but the core is much smaller. Event using "nm" on shows symbols like "_Py_Initialize" so I think the core of the language is in there.

Comment: This is approaching the limits of my expertise now but I can give you an anectdote. I compile my extensions with the python3.7-dev package on ppa:deadsnakes and the resulting .so is only 12.4 kb. Your question was asking about the size of libpython itself but I imagine this doesn't reflect the results of python libraries, at least when compiled with distutils. Try writing your interface and compiling with distutils and I'll wager the result isn't going to be 12 mb.

Comment: Thanks. I just built from the official sources provided but I never heard of python3.7-dev package so I'll look into that tomorrow.